# Xcode 6: Making ipa without iTunes connect credentials

Tags: xcode6, app-store-connect, ipa

Like in Xcode 5, can I make an **ipa** using **Xcode 6** when I am not having credentials of **iTunes connect** to logon.

For certificates, I have exported certificate in p12 and I also have a provisioning profile. So provisioning is not an issue.

I just need an **adhoc** ipa exported from xcode.

Comment: Yes you can, search for *Fake Code Signing Identity Xcode*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote a simple shell script for personal use....

https://github.com/hamdullahshah/xcodeiPa

Usage: CreateBuild.sh

Hope it will help :)